# Data Center Optimalization in AMPL

Tags: linear-programming, ampl

I have such task:

Given are: set of nodes N (each with its power consumption) set of data servers D ⊂ N (each with available storage),
set of computation servers C ⊂ N (each with available computational power), set of edges (each with its capacity), set of
requests D (each with needed CPU power and requested storage).
Demands are served by a pair of servers (storage + computation), traffic of size proportional to storage is generated
between them. A node consumes energy if there is any traffic starting, ending, or passing through it. The task is to assign
demands to servers in such a way that all constraints are met.

Having a power budget B, design a configuration that maximizes the number of served demands.

I need to write the AMPL model to solve this by cplex. Can someone  help me with expressions?

Comment: Please show how far you already got with your AMPL model and define your exact problems with the expression.

Comment: Is this for your homework?